# Include an infogr.am link in header of twenty seventeen theme

Tags: custom-header, theme-twenty-seventeen

Is it possible to use the Infogram link with a graph in the header of the twenty seventeen theme? The result would be a graphic that is automatically refreshing itself whenever there is a change in the data.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you are trying to do? Do you mean add a link to one in the header menu, embed one in a page or make one the header image of a page?

Comment: @yobddigi: Thank you for your comment. My goal is to get a picture of a graph in my header. The picture is generated by infogram.com and I can insert it for example in my text by pasting a link there. Because you get the picture of the graphic by a link to infogram.com I would like to paste the link in a header section and get the graphic. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Ok so you will need to edit the header.php file. Find where it shows the image in the header then you could do it multiple ways. Either check the page ID, or add a custom field in which to add the link then in the header if that fields has a value us the image url as apposed to the default template. At the moment this question is probably off topic.